# Delta function potential and continuity of the derivative

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, dirac-delta-distributions

In Gasiorowicz Quantum Mechanics, 3rd ed, pg.81, he finds the bound states for a delta function potential the following way:
I have the following delta potential:
$V(x)=-\frac{\hbar^2\lambda}{2ma}\delta(x)$
And now, to solve for the bound states $E<0$, i have:
$$\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}-k^2u(x)=-\frac{\lambda}{a}\delta(x)u(x),$$ where
$k^2=\frac{2m|E|}{\hbar^2}$.
Then:$$
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-kx},x>0\\
e^{kx},x<0\\
\end{cases}
$$

And now, my doubt is the following: using this special condition for the derivative at the delta potential we get:
$$(\frac{du}{dx})_{x=0^+}-(\frac{du}{dx})_{x=0^-}=-\frac{\lambda}{a}u(0)
\equiv-k-k=-\frac{\lambda}{a},$$ . Although $u(0)$ is the same for $e^{-kx} $ and $e^{kx}$, in the case where my delta function is at $x\neq0$, which function would I choose? Or if the functions on the right and left of the delta potential were different?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think this implies exp(-kx) was used? For x=0 -kx=0=kx

Comment: I'm so sorry! I wasn't clear! I edited my question further.

Comment: Thanks. Still a bit unclear. Delta function at x!=0 is zero.  Are you asking why for positive x you use exp(-kx) and not exp(kx)? This is required so your wave function can be normalized (finite integeral of the square)

Answer (score 1):

Since the wave function must be continuous everywhere, it can’t make a difference to choose one or the other as they must coincide at the discontinuity.

It the discontinuity is as $x=a$, the simply shifting $x \to x-a$ everywhere will do the trick.